# Travelling to Schengen countries with Refugee Travel Document (Convention 1951) issued by Romania?

Tags: schengen, romania, refugees

What countries allow me to pass their borders visa-free?

Am I allowed to visit and work in EU and Schengen countries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a matter that is not fully harmonized between the Schengen countries.

Romania and some -- but not all! -- Schengen states are parties to the [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](http://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031?_coeconventions_WAR_coeconventionsportlet_languageId=en_GB), created under the auspices of the Council of Europe. If you're going to one of the states that implement the Agreement, you should be allowed visits of up to three months. In practice I can imagine this would be administered by applying the usual Schengen 90/180 day rule to you.

For travel to non-party states, such as Austria or Greece, you would probably need to apply for a visa.

This don't give you any right to work in other states, though -- which is consistent with the fact that even a work-and-residence permit issued by a Schengen state does not allow a third-country national to work in a different Schengen state.

The EU freedom of movement rules apply only to *nationals* of EEA countries, not to non-citizen permanent residents.

Comment: Are you forgetting about [2003/109/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520)?  The refugee travel document might not help, but the residence permit that presumably comes along with it will, and once the person has acquired permanent residence, they have a right of residence in EU countries other than the UK, Ireland, and Denmark.

Comment: @phoog: No, I didn't forget about it -- I didn't know about it in the first place!